# Get Facebook ID on invite game

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the Facebook API to invite friends. But I need at the time you click invite, I receive the facebook id of the invited person. I followed this blog, but it does not delivery FBID.

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html

Comment: What do you want. APP ID?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply...
No, the facebook id user

Comment: did you try to refer to facebook documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't refer to blog posts which are 3 years old. The graph API has changed a lot since then.

Only Canvas games are currently allowed to use the invite friends API.

> The `invitable_friends` API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation. This API is only available on version 2.0 (or later) of the Graph API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends